# jQuery: how to get clicked element position -> textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using wysiwyg and for view i'm using rendered `span` (don't check all details, it's just a small overview)...

So: i have such html code:

```
<p>TEXT123!!!</p>
<strong>Yep!</strong>
```

is it possible to get position where i clicked? For example i clicked between `e` and `p` on the second line and store this value?

And (the main part of my question) set carret position in my textarea to `between e and p on the second line` with some method?

Can this be done by javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by textarea? Is it a textarea element or..?

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna yes element)

Answer (score 0):

html has it native `contenteditable="true"`.
you can put it in any element.

```
<p contenteditable="true">TEXT123!!! <strong>Yep!</strong> </p>
```

Example:
[Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/motion_max/pen/Lpwvxw)

**supported browser:** chrome +4.0, internet explorer +6.0, firefox +3.5, safari +3.1, opera +10.1

Comment: no. any contenteditables in my app...
it's a huge "bug" sphere when i wanna use validations etc